# A small issue about function and closure

Tags: swift, function, closures

```
func runningMetersWithMetersPerDay ( metersPerDay: Int ) -> () -> 
Int {
    var totalMeters = 0
    return {
        totalMeters += metersPerDay
        return totalMeters
    }
}
var planA = runningMetersWithMetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000)
planA()
planA()
```

The first `planA()` print 2000 and the second `planA()`print 4000.
The number accumulates each time I call `planA()`
Why?
What is the use of `var totalMeters = 0` in this function ?
Is `planA()` the same as `runningMetersWith MetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000)` ? 
If not, what's the difference between them ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your method returns a closure, which you excute twice.
The closure *captures* it's environment, in your case the 'outer' variable `totalMeters` and keeps it's value through different calls.

If this is not what you want, you'd have to put `totalMeters` into the closure like this:

```
func runningMetersWithMetersPerDay ( metersPerDay: Int ) -> () ->
Int {
    return {
        var totalMeters = 0
        totalMeters += metersPerDay
        return totalMeters
    }
}
```

---

To answer the question from the comment below:
I've modified the original function and calls, to print out some *hints*:

```
func runningMetersWithMetersPerDay ( metersPerDay: Int ) -> () ->
    Int {
        print ("rMWMD called")
        var totalMeters = 0
        return {
            totalMeters += metersPerDay
            print ("calculated new result: \(totalMeters)")
            return totalMeters
        }
}

print ("start")
var planA = runningMetersWithMetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000) // "rMWMPD called"
print ("got planA")
planA() // "calculated new result:2000"
planA() // "calculated new result:4000"

runningMetersWithMetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000)() // "calculated new result: 2000"
planA() // "calculated new result:6000"
print ("end")
```

`planA` is the result of the function `runningMetersWithMetersPerDay` (a closure of type `(())->Int` - *take `void` paramters and return Int*) , and you then execute the **closure** twice and get the results (2000, 4000).

Now, the function **`runningMetersWithMetersPerDay(metersPerDay:)`** is called again, returns a *new* closure and this return value is then excecuted. It returns 2000, since it's a new closure (although not assigned to a variable).
Think of it as the following:

```
    runningMetersWithMetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000) /* "rMWMPD called" and now call the closure: */ () // "calculated new result: 2000"
```

At the end you execute planA a third time, and since it still holds it's own state (e.g. own `totalMeters` value), it returns 6000.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your answer. But I find another small question. First I called planA() twice and the result prints 2000 and 4000, then I tried to call runningMetersWithMetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000)(), and the result prints 2000, then I called planA() again, the result prints 6000. Now that planA= runningMetersWithMetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000), why is it so different when I called planA() and runningMetersWithMetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000)() ?

Comment: @Wilson: Please look at my modified answer, hope it get's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is normal.
Let's go step by step.

First, you run:

```
var planA = runningMetersWithMetersPerDay (metersPerDay: 2000)
```

What do you execute here?

```
var totalMeters = 0
return {
    totalMeters += metersPerDay
    return totalMeters
}
```

What do you have in planA ?

1. A context with a variable totalMeters
2. A fonction ready to be executed within this context

First run, totalMeters = 0

```
{
    totalMeters += metersPerDay
    return totalMeters
}()
```

Second run, totalMeters = 2000

```
{
    totalMeters += metersPerDay
    return totalMeters
}()
```

new result = 4000

Comment: Kinda answered at the same time as Andreas :) haha! You're welcome Wilson.